# How to set value to textbox in custom grid in magento admin?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I add a custom textbox in a column. but i am not able to fetch its value.[image: here i attach what i did]

I did some this type of coding to show textbox. But the problem is how can i set value for textbox.

```
    $html = '<input type="text" ';
    $html .= 'name="' . $this->getColumn()->getId() . '" ';
    $html .= 'id="' . $this->getColumn()->getId() . '" ';
    $html .= 'value=""';
    $html .= 'class="input-text ' . $this->getColumn()->getInlineCss() . '"/>';
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add script ... I hope you did :)

Comment: i did same as below comment. but i want textbox value which i didn't get because its a custom textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Hello check below code may be help you

```
$this->addColumn("sort_order", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("yourmodulename")->__("Sort Order"),
                "align" =>"left",
                "index" => "sort_order",
                "type"      => "input",
                ));
```

Comment: hi, i did the same thing but i want the textbox value according to there id's on other page i.e id=>value
eg. 168(id)=>2(value) or in array i.e (2,3,4).